# counting with Alphabetic characters

Tags: c#, winforms, math

**Problem**

currently, the code below (IntToAZString) kinda does the job, but not for 100%, i got this piece of code from someone on IRC (Heisenberg).

The problew now is that it starts at a string length of 1, then moves to 2 until it reaches 3, and when it does, it starts at BAA...

It should start at AAA, but that corresponds to 000, which it doesn't like to do, ZZ is 99, BAA is 100...

[image]

i want it to count to Z, and i want to be able to define the string length (which i have kinda solved..)

**What i want to achieve**

String length: 3
so, AAA.

first, A to Z on the last character, when it hits Z, move the middle character up one in the alphabet (ABA)
Repeat with the last character, move the middle one again.
if the middle one reaches Z, move the first one up one letter in the alphabet.

end when the string generated matches the string on the page ( AOE )
or when it reaches ZZZ.

**Current Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CharCounter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private bool ogFound = false;
        private int chars;
        static string IntToAZString(long number)
        {
            string result = "";

            do
            {
                long remainder = number % 26;

                char digit = (char)(remainder + 65);

                result = digit + result;

                number /= 26;
            }
            while (number > 0);

            return result;
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < (Math.Pow(26, chars)); i++)
            {
                listBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(IntToAZString(i));
                });

            }
        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chars = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're code is fine, but you forgot that in your code, 'A' is equivalent to 0. So "B", is equivalent to "AB", and "AAB" (just like 1, is equivalent to 01, and 001).

your output is just like:

```
0,
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10, (there is no 00 before 10)
...
```

When you printing, you should pad the output string to the desired length, with 'A's:

```
listBox1.Items.Add(IntToAZString(i).PadLeft(chars, 'A');
```

and if you like to, print from 1 char output, then 2 chars output (padded with 'A's), then 3 chars output (padded with 'A's), etc...

And another suggestion - Use `StringBuilder` instead of `string` in the `IntToAZString` method:

```
static string IntToAZString(long number)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(chars);

        do
        {
            long remainder = number % 26;

            char digit = (char)(remainder + 65);

            result.Insert(0, digit);

            number /= 26;
        }
        while (number > 0);

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used a Recursive method to do the same.

```
public class Main{
      static char s[]=new char[26];//Char array to store Set of alphabets

public static void main(String args[]){
      long size=1;
    char ch='a';

    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)       //Loop to add alphabets to Char array s[]
        {
        s[i]=(char)(ch+i);
    }

       while(true)          //infinite loop which increases size of the string.
       { recursion(size,"");
        System.out.println("");
        size++;
        }
}

public static void recursion(long size,String prefix)//Recursive method
    {   
    // Base case: size is 0, print prefix
    if(size==0)
    {   System.out.println(prefix);
        return;
    }
     // One by one add all characters from set and recursively 
    // call for size equals to size-1
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
         // Next character of input added
        String newPrefix = prefix + s[i];
         // Size is decreased, because we have added a new character
        recursion(size-1,newPrefix);
    }

}
}
```

[Check the Whole Program here..!](https://github.com/Rishabh-Rathod/Alphabets/blob/master/Alphabets/alphamagic.java)